# Packages installed by one user not available to another in Ubuntu

Tags: software-installation

Possible newbie question here, I'm mainly just a programmer so not so great with Linux. I am installing a couple of packages on a Linux server logged in as one user. When I switch to a different user, these packages are not installed for that user. In the past everything had installed globally for me but doesn't seem so now. What do I have to do to fix this / install globally in the future?

Installations are CUDA and cuDNN installed from debian files from Nvidia's website.

If I'm logged in as the user that I installed them with and I run "nvcc --version" i get the version number back. If I switch to another user and run the same command, I get "The program 'nvcc' is currently not installed."

Comment: You should compare contents of `$PATH` variables of both users (`echo $PATH`). Or compare whole `~/.bashrc` and `~/.profile`. Software installed by APT should become available for all users (except some system utilites in `/sbin` or `/usr/sbin`).

Comment: What kind of "packages"? installed how?

Comment: gcc, CUDA, cuDNN and TensorFlow

Comment: _How_ did you install them?

Comment: All from debian files from Nvidia's website

Comment: Also, do you mean a user on that specific server? Or a different user, as in a different account for a VPS hosting service? The latter is probably a separate VM on the host, and therefore will not have packages installed which were installed in another VM.

Comment: Different users on the same server!

Comment: Please also [edit] your question to provide the additional details. Thanks.

Comment: If they are different users on the same server, and you installed debian packages with `sudo dpkg -i *.deb` then they will almost certainly be available for all users on that specific system. If not, then the debian packages are doing very nasty things.

Comment: Also please indicate exactly how you determined that *"these packages are not installed for that user"*. What specific actions / commands did you perform and what was the error that resulted?

Comment: If I'm logged in as the user that I installed them with and I run "nvcc --version" i get the version number back. If I switch to another user and run the same command, I get "The program 'nvcc' is currently not installed."

Comment: That information should go in your question (using the [edit] button) - fwiw it does sound like a difference in the two users' `PATH` variables

Comment: Okay thanks. What can I do to fix this though?

Comment: Well, `deb` packages don't normally modify a particular user's environment (they have to be installed as `root` anyway). Are you sure you did not take additional configuration steps in the case of the first user (such as making changes to that user's `~/.bashrc` or `~/.profile` files, as suggested by @N0rbert)? if you did, you will either need to make the same changes to the other user's configuration - or find an equivalent system-wide location for them

Answer (score 1):

You should compare contents of `$PATH` variables of both users (echo `$PATH`). Or compare whole `~/.bashrc` and `~/.profile`.

Software installed by APT should become available for all users (except some system utilities in `/sbin` or `/usr/sbin`).